# How to earn the title of Philosopher?

Tags: political-philosophy, metaphilosophy, society

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is everyone considered a “philosopher”?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/is-everyone-considered-a-philosopher)

I commonly hear politicians say that they are philosophers. And a favorite degree offered by diploma mills is philosophy. 
How can one know when their studies or thoughts have become sufficient to warrant one the title of philosopher?

I believe one doesn't need a college degree to be a philosopher. Would it correct logic to say not everyone who graduates with a degree in Philosophy deserves the title of Philosopher?

Is there an accrediting body that vets philosophers, like the FE is to engineers?