# Is philosophy the pursuit of wisdom?

Tags: meaning, principle, wisdom

What is philosophical discourse? What fundamental principles are involved?

Comment: Relevant, if not duplicate: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-is-philosophy

Comment: Philo = Love, Sophos = Wisdom. It is Love. The 'pursuit' part is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on whether you beleive that there is something more profound in the way reality appears to us. If you do so, then philosophical discourse is just about finding this meaning; trying to find this meaning leads to wisdom. If, on the other hand you do not beleive so, then philosophical discourse is just an intellectual game.
For me, there exist a meaning and this is the most fundamental principle: that everything has a meaning. I start from this.

Comment: Isn't this an unnecessary dichotomy? Even if some fundamental meaning is assumed and searched-for, why would this prevent simultaneous research into the untold areas of philosophy unrelated to such meaning?

Comment: I agree with you: searching is part of the path; otherwise, how could this path be discovered? I just emphasize the point that the path must have a convergence point, a purpose.

Comment: The purpose and intent are yours, based in *your* beliefs.

Comment: Sure, ... everything is yours.